# Ruby - Implicit object of a case statement

Tags: ruby, case-statement

In Ruby, is there a way to get the implicit object of a case statement?

```
case 2+2
when '2'
  puts '2'
else
  puts "#{some_object}"
end
```

Where 'some_object' would be the return value of whatever statement was evaluated by case

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No there's not. You'll have to do something like:

```
some_object = 2+2
case some_object
when '2'
  puts '2'
else
  puts some_object
end
```

or

```
case some_object = 2+2
when '2'
  puts '2'
else
  puts some_object
end
```